# Callout from batch issue

Tags: rest-api, batch, scheduled-apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/UsageInputDemo/') 
global class APTS_UsageInputWSDemo{

@HttpPost
global static void loadUsageInputsDemo()
{ 
RestRequest req =RestContext.request;
 Blob body = req.requestBody;
 String requestString = body.toString();
APTS_UsageInputWrapper inputList = 
   (APTS_UsageInputWrapper)JSON.deserialize(
   requestString,APTS_UsageInputWrapper.class);
  List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c> tempData = new List<EQ_TempSSP1Data__c>();
  if(inputList.ValidateOnly)
  {
  validateData(inputList);
   }
  else
  {

   Integer counter = 1;
   APTS_UsageinputWSBatchtoDelTemprecords b1= new 
    APTS_UsageinputWSBatchtoDelTemprecords();
    database.executeBatch(b1,200); // batch will delete existing tempSSP1 
    records first

    APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch b2= new 
      APTS_UsageInput_InsertTempRecordsBatch(inputList);
    database.executeBatch(b2,200); // batch will insert tempssp1 records from 
      load file
    validateData(inputList); ( here I have created a batch for this method 
   logic which will be  called 
        from finish of batch b2. but I am also making callout with future 
    method from this batch.
```

}

Not able to understand how to implement this. I am not sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Queueable instead of @future. You're allowed one Queueable call per execute method of a Batchable, Schedulable, or Queueable class. Alternatively, you could store the records in a variable and make the callout during the next execute/finish method, but that's decidedly more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Actually problem here is, For data load to O1 i have created a batch. from the finish of this batch i  need to call validation logic. Now if i create a batch then i would not be able to call future method. If i create queable class for validation logic then i would not be able to call queable class from finish of the batch.

Comment: @Suren why must you wait until the finish method to validate the data? And yes, you can call a Queueable from a finish method, or even another batchable, if you wanted to. I feel like we're missing too many details to give you the answer you're looking for. Please edit your question to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Sure. Let me paste my code here which i need to move to batch.